# Format captions in kableExtra()

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

Is it possible to format captions in `kableExtra`? I would like to center and bold a caption for a table when knitting to `HTML` in `RMarkdown`. I have tried to wrap the table in a `CSS div` where the text was centered, but this did not produce the intended result.

Sample table:

```
library(kableExtra)
kable(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6), caption = "CENTER") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped")
```

Yields:

[image]

I would like:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the final format is HTML:

write caption within HTML `center` and `strong` tag and set `escape` to `FALSE`.

```
kable(
    data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6), 
    caption = "<center><strong>CENTER</strong></center>",
    escape = FALSE,
    format = "html"
) %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution through css stylesheets. The trick is to identify the correct element. Let's assume a default html document.

```
---
title: "test"
css: template.css
output: html_document 
---
```

The following css script will work.

```
.table-wrapper caption {
color: black;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: xx-large;
}
```

When in doubt, you can always identify the appropriate element by opening the html document in your browser and inspecting it via ctrl+shift+c.