# how to center kable title/caption while keeping rows left aligned in R kableextra

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I want to have the title(caption) of the table centered, but the values of columns left assigned. I also want my caption to be broken into two lines and each line to be centered.

`align` option changes both of them in a same way.

```
head(mtcars) %>%
   kbl(caption = "{first row\\\\  
                    second row}",
          align = "l") %>%
   kable_styling()
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this helps:

```
head(mtcars) %>%    
    kbl(align = "l") %>% 
    add_header_above(data.frame("{first row \\\\ second row}", 12), 
                     monospace = TRUE) %>%
    kable_styling()
```

The result:

[image]

### Update

I assume that you are trying to produce a table in html format. To center the caption and put a line break on the caption texts, you can use html elements: `<center>` for centering and `<br>` for line breaking.

```
head(mtcars) %>%
    kbl(caption = "<center>{first row <br>
                  second row}</center>", 
        align = "l") %>% 
    kable_styling()
```

The result:

[image]

### References

1. [Format captions in kableExtra()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087931/format-captions-in-kableextra)
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element

Comment: thanks but I do not want to add a header, I want my CAPTION to be broken into two lines and each line to be centered.

Comment: OK please check my updated answer.