# How do I center a table caption using Kable and kblextra in R when knitting PDF file?

Tags: r, pdf, formatting, r-markdown, kable

This problem occurs when using the kbl() function to create tables in R if the table's caption is too long. If the caption is too long, the text begins to wrap to the next line, but then it becomes left-justified.

Sometimes the caption is short enough can be solved by adding the landscape argument to the style options, but I'd like a solution that is more flexible. The styling options for kbl offer lots of tools to manipulate the table cells, but I'm having difficulty doing that to the table captions.  Here is example code that would result in the problem I'm having.

```
kbl(mtcars, caption = "This is a really long title that will go past the borders when knitting to PDF in portrait mode. I'd love to figure out how to keep it centered even if the text is really long.", 
    booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "", align = "c") %>% 
    kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"))
```

Adding the "hold_position" argument works for keeping the table in centered and in place, but the caption doesn't behave the same. Also, adding "< center > < center/ >" around the caption works if knitting to HTML, but I'd like a solution that works when knitting to PDF.

Additionally, using \n to do linebreaks doesn't seem to work like it does for other packages like ggplot().

Comment: The example seemed to work with your title : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72279046/how-to-center-kable-title-caption-while-keeping-rows-left-aligned-in-r-kableextr

Comment: This example only works if you are ok with the table caption being more part of the table as an additional header. It looks ok standalone, but might be odd if it was with other tables that were just printed normally. 

The //// breaks and <center> arguments only work when knitting to HTML, not PDF though.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use LaTeX's `caption` package with the option of `justification=centering` (i.e. `\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}` in the `header-includes` field of the YAML section).

````
---
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
kbl(mtcars,
  caption = "This is a really long title that will go past the borders when knitting to PDF in portrait mode. I'd love to figure out how to keep it centered even if the text is really long.",
  booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "", align = "c"
)  %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"))
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great for my project and for others reading this, it should work so long as you are happy with using center justification for all of the table captions in your PDF output.

Answer (score 0):

Without the additional LaTeX package which @Carlos Luis Rivera has shown, I failed to find any possible way to center the caption by using `kable`. Therefore, in case you don't want additional LaTeX package, I would recommend using `flextable` package instead of `kable` and `kableExtra`.  In the following example I use `pdf-latex`:

````
```{r}
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)

set_flextable_defaults(fonts_ignore = TRUE)
mtcars |> rownames_to_column(var = "carmodel") |> 
    flextable() |> theme_zebra() |>
    align(j = ~.-carmodel, align = "center", part = "all") |>
    autofit(add_w = 0) |>
    set_caption(caption = "This is a really long title that will go past the borders 
        when knitting to PDF in portrait mode. I'd love to figure out how to keep it 
        centered even if the text is really long.")
````

The resulted PDF table:

[image]